# Neovim 0.2.2 Can't update

Tags: neovim

Currently, I have NVIM 0.2.2, meaning that I can't do most plugins in nvim. If you have an answer, I would appreciate it :)

I have now been looking for a solution to update neovim from the terminal but it always says: "E: The update command takes no arguments".

Answer (score 0):

Yep same issue as me, i'm stuck in 0.6 in linux mint, anyway i solved that by downloading the .appimage version from the official neovim github.
Here's the link: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/stable

Comment: Thank you but my kernel (i believe) doesn't let me install app images

Comment: Damn that sucks, anyway it's been 2 month, how are you doing? also have you solved the issue?